# how to put six editbox horizontally

Tags: android, eclipse

I am beginner in android development

How can place six  editbox horizontally side by side without any  overlapping each other in screen. The following is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10" />
```

With Thanks
Pol

Comment: combine Techfist and Renan Bandeira answers. use LinearLayout and add it to HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by wraping all your EditBoxes inside a `HorizontalScrollView`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` and add `"android:layout_weight="1"` to all the `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

Put your EditTexts here.

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `EditText` inside a horizontal `LinearLayout`, set their `width to 0` and `weight to 1`. They will be equally distributed on the screen without any overlap.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText04"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```